# Icon/image over UIButton iPhone

Tags: iphone

If I want an image on my UIButton, and I still want to use the default white button. Is it ok to add an image(icon) over some parts of the button?

I have a button with the text 'Show on map' and I want a icon to the right.

Is this the only approach or are there other possibilities? When I add an icon over the button some parts of the button won't be "clickable".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a custom button that has an image the 'icon' and then the rest is transparent and then overlay this button over the standard one and give them the same action.

An easier way would just to be create an image that is the button exactly as you want it and use the 'custom button' style and use this as the backgroundImage.